# How to create a static class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have 2 classes:

```
object TrimNCompressConstants {
  var REQUEST_CODE = 101
  var EXTRA_VIDEO_PATH = "EXTRA_VIDEO_PATH"
  var EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE"
  var RESULT_SUCCESS = 102 
}
```

and

```
class VideoUtil (var context : Context?) {
  fun show (code : Int) {
    TrimNCompressConstants.REQUEST_CODE = code
  }
}
```

When in call `show()`, it gives an error for `TrimNCompressConstants.REQUEST_CODE = code`:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Can anybody help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use class named *Constants* to store mutable variables?

Comment: Show your stack trace.

Comment: an `ExceptionInInitializerError` is occurs in static *initializer / static initialization*, I don't know why you are reported such an error?

Comment: It tested your code and it works for me

Comment: I admit I don;t know a lot about how Kotlin initializes properties in an object but it almost looks like it is happening after you access it. Can you try annotating your vars in your object with [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods) and let us know if that fixes it?